# Possible to get type of Eigen::MatrixBase<T> &

Tags: c++, eigen

having a Eigen::MatrixBase & data, are there any way to get if it is a float or double matrix?
I need to create an new complex matrix of the same size and type as the MatrixBase.

If it is MatrixXf then i need to create MatrixXcf, and if MatrixXd i need MatrixXcD.?

```
template <typename A>
        int dowork(const Eigen::MatrixBase<A>& data)
```

Comment: Don't you know the type already, via the `A` template type?

Comment: I would assume that A contains the information yes, but i dont know how to use that to create either my complex float or complex double matrix.

Comment: No, A will be a type of matrix.

Comment: But how do i then create either a MatrixXcf or MatrixXcd depending on what type of matrix A are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty simple, just use the A::RealScalar typedef to build your complex type:

```
template <typename A>
int dowork(const Eigen::MatrixBase<A>& data) {
    typedef Matrix<std::complex<typename A::RealScalar, Dynamic, Dynamic> MatCplx;
    ...
```

Comment: Wont A::Scalar be the std::complex<float or double> and then your code will be std::complex<std::complex<float or double>> ?

Comment: @s093294 That might be a typo, but even if it is it's easy to fix. Anyways, one of `Matrix<std::complex<typename A::Scalar>, Dynamic, Dynamic>` or `Matrix<typename A::Scalar, Dynamic, Dynamic>` should work. (I'd bet it's the latter, but I don't know off the top of my head.)

Comment: your question said that dowork takes a matrix of float or double, so A::Scalar must be either float or double. Now if dowork can also take complex types, then use A::RealScalar to be sure, as in my modified answer

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100 percent sure I understand the question being asked, but I think you asking to having another matrix allocated of the same time type after some condition is met? Do you want this new matrix to not allow data types that don't match the type?

If not, because you are using template classes you have a lot of freedom and can just use general template data types. Also look into representing the matrix using vector formats for ease of use. Maybe even sparse format stuff like so

```
// Local variables used.
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int endN, endM;

// Iterates through matrix checking when last matrix value is reached for end point.
while (endN != sizeN && endM != sizeM) {
    if (a == sizeN) {
        b++;
        a = 0;
        endM = b;
    } else {
        if (Matrix[a][b] != 0) {
            // Stores non-zero matrix values in queue SpareseFormat.
            SparseFormat.push(a);
            SparseFormat.push(b);
            SparseFormat.push(Matrix[a][b]);
        }
        endN = a;
        a++;
    }
}
```

Sorry if I totally didn't understand your question. It has been a long night :P