# Compilation Error Using template programming with Eigen C++ library

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, eigen, eigen3

I downloaded Eigen (3) library and started using it. I wrote a template function and declared a local variable of 'template type' inside the function. I am getting the following compilation error.

---

```
$ g++ EigenTest.cpp

EigenTest.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void myFunc(Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>&) [with Type1 = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>]’:
EigenTest.cpp:24:10:   required from here
EigenTest.cpp:16:26: error: conversion from ‘Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, 1>::Scalar {aka double}’ to non-scalar type ‘Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>’ requested
   Type1 tmp = matrix(0, 0);
```

---

"EigenTest.cpp" is given below.

---

```
#include "Eigen/Dense"

#include <iostream>

template<typename Type1>
void myFunc(Eigen::MatrixBase<Type1>& matrix)
{
int i=matrix.rows();
Type1 tmp = matrix(0, 0);           // getting compiler error here
std::cout<<"tmp is ->"<<tmp<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
Eigen::MatrixXd m(2,2);
m.setConstant(100); 
myFunc(m);
return 0;
}
```

---

I also tried using 'typename Type1 tmp = matrix(0, 0);'
This also didn't work!

How to fix this?
In normal C++ template programming (without Eigen), I can define a local variable inside a template function as 'Type1 tmp;"

Comment: What is `Type1`? And the program you show in the question is not the one that generated the errors. Please show the *real* program.

Comment: Sorry for missing out some part of the code in he initial post. Type1 is actually 'template typename'

Comment: Simply put though, it looks like the return from the call `matrix(0, 0)` (which I don't quite understand, but it is early) does not match the type `Type1` - whatever that is, you haven't shown us what `Type1` is defined as, presumably in some typedef somewhere.

Comment: I suggest you learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Comment: Guys, the code was missing `<>`, I now get the error as described by the OP.

Answer (score 3):

In `Eigen::MatrixBase<Type1>`, `Type1` is not a scalar type but the type of the actual expression. In your example it will be MatrixXd but if myFunc is called on, e.g., m.block(...), then `Type1` will be a Block<...>. To obtain the scalar type, you can use Type1::Scalar:

```
template<typename Type1>
void myFunc(Eigen::MatrixBase<Type1>& matrix)
{
  typename Type1::Scalar Scalar;
  Scalar tmp = matrix(0, 0);
}
```

And if you need a matrix type that is similar to `Type1`, use `Type1::PlainObject`, e.g.:

```
typename Type1::PlainObject mat = 2 * matrix * matrix.transpose();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As you suggested, I used Type1::Scalar and it is working now.

Comment: i think the bottom code is supposed to be `Type1::PlainObject`, not `PlainObjectType`

Comment: @ofloveandhate, you're right, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `MatrixBase` uses the "CRTP" (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)), the template argument is actually the type deriving from it.  Thus in your use of the method `myFunc()`, `Type1` is actually representing `Eigen::MatrixXd`, and I **think** that *you* think `Type1` is a double.  So, this line:

```
Type1 tmp = matrix(0, 0);
```

In the documnetation for this library (see [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html)) the typedef for `MatrixXd` is a matrix of doubles, so I guess the return from `matrix(0, 0)` is a double, and as tmp is of `Type1` which is `Eigen::MatrixXd`, the one will not go into the other.

Scanning the docummentation I think it MIGHT be better for your function to take a `Matrix` as an argument, that way the scalar type should be available.  Something like this:

```
template<class T, int rows, int cols, int opts, int maxR, int maxC > 
void myFunc( Eigen::Matrix<T, rows, cols, opts, maxR, maxC>& matrix )
{
    T tmp = matrix(0, 0);
}
```

(Looks dreadful though!!!  ;-) )

Comment: OK, error output is even more misleading than I thought. Can't you use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148978/possible-to-get-type-of-eigenmatrixbaset) to get at the underlying data type?

Comment: Not completely misleading.  In the error message `Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, 1>::Scalar` refers to `double` (in your case) and then the message continues that it can't turn that into a `Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>`, which is `Type1`, the type that derived from `MatrixBase` and was also its template parameter.  Simples!  (Not!)  As for the other solution, could well be - I don't know this library, I just quickly scanned the documentation for the source of the error.

Comment: This might be one of those cases where MSVC could just give the most useful error (as it usually lists all the types relevant to a template instantiation). Anyways, nice work finding the real issue `:-)`.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Gladder still for an upvote and a tick.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `Type1` is deduced to be `double` (because [`Eigen::MatrixXd` is defined that way](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__matrixtypedefs.html#ga890734166f62e879d08de6822587faed)).

You are then trying to do

```
Type1 tmp = matrix(0, 0);
```

And I'm afraid my Eigen knowledge isn't enough, so I ran it through Clang 3.3, and got this error:

```
test.cpp:9:7: error: no viable conversion from 'Scalar' (aka 'double') to
      'Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>'
Type1 tmp = matrix(0, 0);           // getting compiler error here
      ^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:17:1: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'myFunc<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >' requested here
myFunc(m);
^
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:210:5: note: candidate constructor not viable:
      no known conversion from 'Scalar' (aka 'double') to
      'internal::constructor_without_unaligned_array_assert' for 1st argument
    Matrix(internal::constructor_without_unaligned_array_assert)
    ^
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:284:25: note: candidate constructor not
      viable: no known conversion from 'Scalar' (aka 'double') to 'const
      Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> &' for 1st argument
    EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE Matrix(const Matrix& other)
                        ^
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:272:25: note: candidate template ignored:
      could not match 'MatrixBase<type-parameter-0-0>' against 'double'
    EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE Matrix(const MatrixBase<OtherDerived>& other)
                        ^
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:292:25: note: candidate template ignored:
      could not match 'ReturnByValue<type-parameter-0-0>' against 'double'
    EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE Matrix(const ReturnByValue<OtherDerived>& other)
                        ^
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:303:25: note: candidate template ignored:
      could not match 'EigenBase<type-parameter-0-0>' against 'double'
    EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE Matrix(const EigenBase<OtherDerived> &other)
                        ^
1 error generated.
```

which is telling me you cannot call `matrix` like that, with two 0's as arguments. It's also weird syntax because the `MatrixBase` class does not have an `operator()` which you seem to be trying to calling.